# MS Teams bot notification

Tags: python, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I'm using bot framework with Python and I have deployed bot service in Azure cloud. I created an endpoint for notification and I basically want to notify all groups without previously installing or assigning bot in specific groups.

In the documentation there is a section which explains that you can proactively install your app using Graph, but it's part of a code and it is not helping too much.
[Link to docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=python). How I can send message to all groups without assigning bot to the group?

```
async def _send_proactive_message(data): 
  #i need a proper context and other infos just from http post request

async def notify(req: Request) -> Response: 
   body = await req.json()
   await _send_proactive_message(body)
   return Response(status=HTTPStatus.OK, text="Proactive messages have been sent")

APP = web.Application(middlewares=[aiohttp_error_middleware])
APP.router.add_post("/api/notify", notify)
```

Comment: When you say you want to notify all groups, what do you mean by groups? Are you talking about team channels or group chats?

Comment: @EtherealNP Are you trying to send a message in a bot installed team or any specific team, Could you please explain scenario in detail.

Comment: @KyleDelaney to channels in team groups

Comment: @Chetana-MSFT to channel which bot is not installed or interacted with some users from the channel

Comment: @EtherealNP You can send message to teams using send message graph api. Please check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and try that helps. If you are trying something else please share more details.

Comment: @EtherealNP Please let us know if your issue has been resolved.